# Flask - getting a value from a Vue MultiSelect Element

Tags: python, flask, vue.js

I have a Vue-multiselect, as in this example (not mine)
https://jsfiddle.net/gmsa/04jvjuv3/

I'm trying to get the value in the multi select element and POST it back to my Flask app.

HTML

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <multiselect id="multi", name = "multi" :multiple="true" :hide-selected="true" :selected="selected" :options="options" :taggable="false" @update="updateSelected"></multiselect>
    <button type="submit" value="l1" >Load</button>
    </form>
```

Flask

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print request.form.getlist('multi')
    #prints an empty list
    print request.form['multi']
    #hits a bad request error
```

I've been klutzing about with this for a long time now - why can't I get the value from the form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that vue-multiselect is meant [to be handled using pure javascript](https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect/issues/112). So, you could just use the solution implemented by the user in that issue.

In HTML:

```
<input style="display: none;" :value="selected" name="multiselect">
```

Inside the form, and in python:

```
request.form.get('multiselect').split(',')
```

The `split` is in case multiple options were selected.

BTW, that fiddle uses old versions of both vue and multiselect, but that's unrelated.